# Apply a formula to a dataset

Tags: r, variance

I have a dataset with 2 columns; one for dates and one for the daily returns of a financial index.

I need to use that data to estimate the variance of the monthly data by applying the following formula (see the picture for the formula and the description).

[image: Formula to be used]

I managed to obtain the exponentially weighted average return by using the following:

```r
subset_MKTdaily$ewma_returns <- EMA(subset_MKTdaily$AUT, ratio = 60/61, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I tried using the following function to compute the variance, but the code isn't working and I get error messages:

```r
calculate_variance <- function(T) {
  d<-60/61
  # Step 1: Create a new variable to store the variance values
  subset_MKTdaily$variance <- NA  # Creating a new column named "variance" in the dataset
  
  # Step 2: Calculate the variance using a vectorized approach
  for (t in 1:nrow(subset_MKTdaily)) {
    i_values <- min(0, T-2)  # Limit i_values up to T - 2
    variance <- 23 * sum((d^i_values) * ((subset_MKTdaily$AUT[t - i_values - 1] - subset_MKTdaily$ewma_returns[t])^2))
    subset_MKTdaily$variance[t] <- variance
  }
  
  # Return the dataset with the calculated variance
  return(data)
}
```

but I am unsure how the code works and how to use the formula to predict the monthly variance. Could someone please help me out here?